# default login for anonymous authentication IIS FTP server

Tags: windows, windows-10, ftp, authentication, iis

I just installed the IIS FTP server on my machine and selected to use anonymous autentication, it didn't ask any password to use but when open in the browser ftp://localhost it does request an username and password. Which one should I use? I tried leave the `anonymous` username with password `anonymous@localhost` or leave password field empty but either way it return the error:

> 530-User cannot log in.  Win32 error:     Error details: An error
>   occurred during the authentication process. 530 End

I tried to set an login by ISS > sites > default FTP > FTP authentication > anonymous authentication > fill with foo username and baa password, tried to login and received same error.

What's the proper username to the FTP?

Comment: Did you ever fix this? I have the same error.

Comment: sorry, I don't remeber what I did at time.. but I think I ended up using something else than IIS...